# ColorPicker on jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I need color picker on my page.
First, I placed Primefaces' colorpicker, but when I tried to use it, I received "IllegalArgumentException: text/xml is not a supported mime type". Probably this occurs because I use my own jquery library, which has no colorpicker element, and it overrides Primefaces' one.

So, I tried it in other way. I used "jscolor" library which turns any input field to colorpicker. I got component:

```
<h:inputText value="#{searchManagedBean.selectedColor}" class="color"/>
```

It works perfectly, but when I submit form, value in backing bean doesn't update. In backing bean I have getter and setter for this field, so I can't figure out what is the reason of this problem.

Could you help me with one of these problems, or maybe provide another solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If I update the value in some other element, value in backing bean updates too. So, now I have something like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{searchManagedBean.selectedColor}" class="color">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="outcolor"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText style="display: none" id="outcolor" value="#searchManagedBean.selectedColor}"/>
```

For me, it's very strange behaviour. I don't know why it works, but it works!

Comment: Do not include jquery as it is already included by PrimeFaces. That could be the reason of this problem.

Comment: I am developing portlets on liferay portal. So, jquery is used in portal theme for some theme elements, and is included by default to all portlets. I can't influence this. But I think this was the root of the problem too.